# Nested if and normal if statements

Tags: c#, winforms

Hi have have an if statement inside the event of a button, when i run the code and select the first radio and click on the button(which does the calculations) it prints it out on the label, but when i click on the second radio button and click the button to calculate the answer nothing happens at all. Any ideas please

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
          if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
             {
                 double a;  // have to declare double here as we cannot include it below as bool is a rue or false statment

                 bool success1 = double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out a); // take in value as true or false

                 if (success1) // check if it was parsed successful
                 {
                     label4.Text = ConvertToCel(a).ToString(); // now set it in label
                 }
                 else if (radioButton1.Checked == false && radioButton2.Checked == true)
                 {
                     double a1;

                     bool success = double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out a1);

                     if (success){
                         label3.Text = ConvertToFar(a1).ToString();
                     }
                 }
                 else if (radioButton1.Checked == false && radioButton2.Checked == false)
                 {
                     label4.Text = "Please select an option from above";
                 }
             }
         }�
```

Comment: Watch out which `else` is matching which `if`.

Comment: Your entire code runs only if radioButton1 is checked because you put everything inside `if (radioButton1.Checked == true)` block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because radio buttons are mutually exclusive, and you are only executing the code if `radioButton1` is checked. You should probably also handle the case where the textbox could not be parsed correctly (i.e. if the user enters something that cannot be converted to a double). I've included this below.

```
double a;
bool success = double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out a);

if (success)
{
    if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
    {
        label4.Text = ConvertToCel(a).ToString();
    }
    else if (radioButton2.Checked == true)
    {
        label3.Text = ConvertToFar(a).ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        label4.Text = "Please select an option from above";
    }
}
else
{
    label4.Text = "The value could not be convered to a number.";
}
```

Comment: where would i declare a1 as you have assigned a to success @Brett Wolfington

Comment: There is no need. a1 was the same value as a.

Comment: im getting an error telling me that a1 does not exist in the current context

Comment: plus a and a1 are from two separate methods

Comment: @yemioladejo The value of both `a` and `a1` comes from textBox1. There is no need for two separate variables. Convert once, use as many times as necessary.

Comment: Sorry. That was a typo on my part. I fixed it.

Comment: but a and a1 are from two different methods

Comment: i have added the methods for a and a1

Comment: @yemioladejo You don't have to match parameter names with actual values. So, you can say `ConvertToFar(a)`, `ConvertToFar(999)` and even `ConvertToFar(a * 999)`. These values will be mapped to `a1`.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are checking for the condition of radiobutton1 being checked first and then nested other conditions inside it, so if the first condition is false the other conditions are not being checked, so to avoid that you should bring the other else if-conditions outside the first if-condition, you can use:-

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double a;  // have to declare double here as we cannot include it below as bool is a rue or false statment

    bool success1 = double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out a); // take in value as true or false

    if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
    {
        if (success1) // check if it was parsed successful
        {
            label4.Text = ConvertToCel(a).ToString(); // now set it in label
        }
    }
    else if (radioButton1.Checked == false && radioButton2.Checked == true)
    {
        if (success)
        {
            label3.Text = ConvertToFar(a).ToString();
        }
    }
    else if (radioButton1.Checked == false && radioButton2.Checked == false)
    {
        label4.Text = "Please select an option from above";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this helps, i'll look out for similar errors next time

Comment: hi i'm gettin an error saying a1 does not exist in the current context

Comment: i have edited the code it should work now, I had committed a mistake and used a1 instead of a that contains the double value

Comment: i have edited the original code so you can see how i used a and a1 as they are from two different methods

Comment: a and a1 doesn't matter here because a and a1 are both local variables, both in-case of the event and the methods that you have defined, the code that I have posted should work, it doesn't matter what variable name I pass the value with finally value that is received is not dependent upon the variable name with which it is being sent

Comment: great happy that you found the solution :)

Comment: You should click on CheckMark if my answer was correct and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

That's because you have put the `else` on the `if` statement inside the first `if` statement. The checks for radiobutton 2 will only be run if the condition in the first `if` statement is true.

End the block for the first `if` statement before the `else` statements:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (radioButton1.Checked == true)
    {
        double a;  // have to declare double here as we cannot include it below as bool is a rue or false statment

        bool success1 = double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out a); // take in value as true or false

        if (success1) // check if it was parsed successful
        {
            label4.Text = ConvertToCel(a).ToString(); // now set it in label
        }
    }
    else if (radioButton1.Checked == false && radioButton2.Checked == true)
    {
        double a1;

        bool success = double.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out a1);

        if (success){
            label3.Text = ConvertToFar(a1).ToString();
        }
    }
    else if (radioButton1.Checked == false && radioButton2.Checked == false)
    {
        label4.Text = "Please select an option from above";
    }
}
```